# How to put timer into a GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, timer

I have a GUI with a form for people to fill up and I would like to put a countdown timer at the top right hand corner of the page

Heres the method for the timer to get the remaining time. Say my form class is  FillForm and the timer method is found in Timer.

How do I put a dynamic (constantly updating) timer inside of the GUI?

```
public String getRemainingTime() {
    int hours = (int)((this.remainingTime/3600000) % 60);
    int minutes = (int)((this.remainingTime/60000) % 60);
    int seconds = (int)(((this.remainingTime)/1000) % 60);

    return(format.format(hours) +  ":" +  format.format(minutes)+ 
          ":" +  format.format(seconds));       
}
```

GUI is built using NetBeans GUI builder.

Comment: What kind of GUI is this?

Comment: See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), assuming this is a swing app.

Comment: Oh its a Java GUI built using NetBeans GUI builder

Comment: yes you can add it into jPanel

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
      import javax.swing.Timer; 
      Timer  timer=new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
        //code here 
     }
     });
     timer.start();
    //timer.stop()
```

Every  one Seconds Timer Execute.

```
   Try This Demo :

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Counter {

private static int cnt;
static JFrame f;
public static void main(String args[]) {

 f=new JFrame();
 f.setSize(100,100);
 f.setVisible(true);


 ActionListener actListner = new ActionListener() {

 @Override

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  cnt += 1;
 if(cnt%2==0)
 {
    f.setVisible(true);
 }
 else
 {
    f.setVisible(false);
 }
 }

};

Timer timer = new Timer(500, actListner);

 timer.start();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Could i add this into a Swing.JPanel or something?

Answer (score 1):

You should abstract your timer into a UI component. `JLabel` seems the most suited as it is a text that you want to display.

```
public class TimerLabel extends JLabel {
    // Add in your code for 'format' and 'remainingTime'.
    // Note that the first time that 'getText' is called, it's called from the constructor
    // if the superclass, so your own class is not fully initialized at this point.
    // Hence the 'if (format != null)' check

    public TimerLabel() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public String getRemainingTime() {
        int hours = (int) ((this.remainingTime / 3600000) % 60);
        int minutes = (int) ((this.remainingTime / 60000) % 60);
        int seconds = (int) (((this.remainingTime) / 1000) % 60);

        return (format.format(hours) + ":" + format.format(minutes) + ":" + format.format(seconds));
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        if (format != null) {
            return getRemainingTime();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> "Could i add this into a Swing.JPanel or something?"

Just put it in the constructor of your form class. Declare the `Timer timer;` as a class member and not locally scoped so that you can use the `start()` method like in a button's `actionPerformed`. Something like

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public Timer timer = null;

    public GUI() {
        timer = new Timer (500, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (timerGetsToZero) {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                } else {
                    timeLabel.setText(getRemainingTime());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
    }
}
```